# bootstrap modal content does not show on specific platforms

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I have an odd issue that has been driving me crazy, for a flask web app. I have the following button that opens a modal called `addincident`

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addincident" class="btn btn-default">Add New</button>
```

Which is supposed to open this modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="addincident" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Escalate an incident</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                           < removed for brevity >
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <button id="submit" type="Button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>  
</div>
```

Now, this works on Fedora 22 and 24 on Chrome 52 and Firefox 46 and newer. However, some users on Fedora 23 report that the modal never appears on any of those browsers - all they get is the darkening screen for the overlay, but not the actual modal.

I have just today had the first report of this behavior on Fedora 24 with Chrome 52. The users reporting this problem say there are no errors in the browser console, and on the webserver side all I see are the standard GETs coming in - no errors or anything from flask or gunicorn.

Most of what I've seen from Google-ing this problem say it's an issue with having a `fade` in the modal, but as you can see I don't have one.

Thoughts?

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? And where on the page are you rendering the modal content? Have your tried rendeting #addincident  just before the closing </body> tag

Comment: Using 3.3.7. #addincident is already just before the closing </body>.